# Release Management upgrade to 2013.4 - 500 error when creating release

Tags: tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

After upgrading to Release Management 2013.4, we tried creating a release in the client that's also on 2013.4. We've repaired the server (looks like it needed to install .NET 4.5.1) but the error still is the same:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred in the application: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.\n at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.WebRequest.PlatformHttpClient.EndGetResponse...
```

When we look at the logs, we get a ton of errors with system.servicemodel (webhost failed to process a request) and release management (data at the root level is invalid. line 2, position 1).

Any ideas what this is? We tried to enable detailed logging, but can't because we can't create a release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that it's an issue with installing the RM server with HTTPS (default) when it needs to be HTTP. So when we uninstalled and reinstalled RM Server 2013.4 and configured it to HTTP, everything worked!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d0a9d3f1-05d1-4e4c-b44a-93e9bb4b9044/after-upgrading-to-release-management-update-2-i-cannot-deploy-anything?forum=tfsbuild